# TCL command with spaces parsing as Â

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to send command which includes spaces,
I got the following error -
"`system1Â -loadChangeÂ "+10"Â -portAddressÂ "10.10.X.X/1/15â€`"
ecah space replaced by `Â`.
The full command is:

```
av::perform ChangeLoadForPort system1 -loadChange "+10" -portAddress "10.10.X.X/1/15”
```

`X.X` is the IP.

Comment: It's probably your editor that changes minus signs and double quotes into so-called smart dashes and smart quotes. Use an editor that is set up for writing code rather than documents.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `Â`  (a `Â` followed by a space) is the ISO 8859-1 interpretation of the sequence of bytes that make a non-breaking space in UTF-8. (It's also the same with ISO 8859-15 and a few other encodings.) `â€` is another tell-tale. That you're seeing this points to *two* problems:

1. Various bits and pieces of the systems you're dealing with are disagreeing on what encodings are in use. That's Bad News, but would be just theoretically a problem if your code stuck to ASCII. (Almost all encodings have the majority of ASCII as a subset.)
2. Your code has unexpected non-ASCII characters in it, and that's just not going to work. You're probably being sabotaged by whatever program you're using to edit text; a programmer's editor is strongly recommended, and not a word processor.

Comment: The name for this sort of problem is “mojibake” and no, I can't be bothered to figure out what the non-UTF8 encoding in the mix is.

Comment: so how my code should encode? UTF-8? ASCII?

Comment: I don't know, but _keeping your code as ASCII_ tends to avoid virtually all problems. (If there's layers of complexity hiding in there, that's the one thing that will make it through correctly.) I _can_ say that non-breaking spaces don't work as word separators in Tcl code when the code is correctly understood, so you have syntactic things to fix for sure. Fixing encoding mismatches… requires knowing all the moving parts and what encodings they're _currently_ using.